# Interpreting nm output after rejected app

Tags: ios, review, nm, otool

my app was rejected by Apple, because somehow my app uses private API's.
Apple said that my app uses

framework: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation': CFHashBytes

I couldn't find anything in the code, so I searched stackoverflow and fout out that I can use otool or strings.

With string I find two "hash" calls (wherever they are) and using nm, I get the following output:

nm Sporty\ Architect | grep hash

0000000100077490 T __TFO16Sporty_Architect12ActivityTypeg9hashValueSi
0000000100056240 T __TFO16Sporty_Architect12RotationModeg9hashValueSi
0000000100064480 T __TFO16Sporty_Architect13DraggedSliderg9hashValueSi
000000010003e3a0 T __TFO16Sporty_Architect8FileTypeg9hashValueSi
000000010003d910 T __TFO16Sporty_Architect9DateRangeg9hashValueSi
0000000100021360 T __TFO16Sporty_Architect9ModelModeg9hashValueSi
                 U __TFSig9hashValueSi
00000001000777b0 T __TTWO16Sporty_Architect12ActivityTypes8HashableS_FS1_g9hashValueSi
00000001000562e0 T __TTWO16Sporty_Architect12RotationModes8HashableS_FS1_g9hashValueSi
0000000100064500 T __TTWO16Sporty_Architect13DraggedSliders8HashableS_FS1_g9hashValueSi
000000010003e9d0 T __TTWO16Sporty_Architect8FileTypes8HashableS_FS1_g9hashValueSi
000000010003e080 T __TTWO16Sporty_Architect9DateRanges8HashableS_FS1_g9hashValueSi
0000000100021500 T __TTWO16Sporty_Architect9ModelModes8HashableS_FS1_g9hashValueSi

I think the U __TFSig9hashValueSi is it, isn't it? But now the question...how can i narrow this down any further?

It is beyond me, why Apple offers a validate button that shows that everything is OK and once the app is in review, it gets rejected for something, that could clearly be detected at compile time (or at least when it is submitted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use any external API or framework, CFHashBytes is present only in Swift framework.

I had this issue with two Apps. I have sent this message to the Resolution Center and now both have been approved:

"Hello,

I think that there is an error. The only file that contains that non-public API is libswiftFoundation.dylib, framework used in Swift Apps. Xcode uses it automatically. Please, check it again.

Many thanks."

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I saw that I had a method that used the same (and an additional parameter) parameters than the CFHasBytes one. The Mrthod was called getBytes(bytes:length:index:). I can see why an automated test fould fail at this. I renamed the method and will submit again, if it fails again, I will add your comment. Thanks.